# Formatar java.time.Duration para String

Tags: java, data

O código abaixo está produzindo a seguinte saída:

```
Resultado: PT2H30M
```

Eu gostaria que fosse:

```
Resultado: 2:30
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer?

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class TesteDuration {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDateTime primeiraData = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 10, 14, 00, 00);
    LocalDateTime segundaDate = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.JANUARY, 10, 16, 30, 00);

    Duration testeDuration = Duration.between(primeiraData, segundaDate);
    System.out.println("Resultado: " + testeDuration.toString());

}
```

Comment: Esse código não dá esse resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma outra forma de fazer, complementando [a resposta do diegofm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179085/132), é você ir subtraindo os campos de data um a um para retirar dele, cada componente.

Por exemplo:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class TesteDurationNovo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDateTime primeiraData = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 10, 14, 00, 00);
        LocalDateTime segundaDate = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.JANUARY, 10, 16, 30, 00);

        Duration testeDuration = Duration.between(primeiraData, segundaDate);
        long dias = testeDuration.toDays();
        Duration d2 = testeDuration.minus(dias, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        long horas = d2.toHours();
        Duration d3 = d2.minus(horas, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        long minutos = d3.toMinutes();
        Duration d4 = d3.minus(minutos, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        long segundos = d4.getSeconds();
        Duration d5 = d4.minus(segundos, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        long nanos = d5.toNanos();
        Duration d6 = d5.minus(nanos, ChronoUnit.NANOS);

        System.out.println("Total: " + dias + " dias, " + horas + " horas, " + minutos + " minutos, " + segundos + " segundos, " + nanos + " ns.");
        System.out.println("Resultado: " + testeDuration.toString());
        if (!d6.isZero()) throw new AssertionError(d6.toString());
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Total: -365 dias, -21 horas, -30 minutos, 0 segundos, 0 ns.
Resultado: PT-8781H-30M
```

Isso significa que o seu período é de 365 dias, 21 horas e 30 minutos **negativos**. O período é negativo porque a `primeiraData` é posterior a `segundaDate`. Isso pode ser arrumado se você simplesmente trocar as datas que você atribui a cada variável, ou se você trocar a ordem dos parâmetros no método [`between(Temporal, Temporal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-), ou ainda se você chamar o método [`abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#abs--) da `Duration` e só então armazenar o resultado na variável `testeDuration`.

Não é possível subtrair-se meses ou anos de uma forma simples e direta do `Duration` porque nem todos os meses e nem todos os anos têm o mesmo tamanho. Por isso é que não existem os métodos `toMonths()` ou `toYears()`.

Quanto ao resultado do [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--), esse `PT-8781H-30M` quer dizer apenas que a duração é de -8781 horas e -30 minutos. A `String` retornada sempre vai conter a quantidade de horas, minutos e segundos da `Duration`, podendo ser a quantidade de segundos fracionária para os casos que incluam nanosegundos e a quantidade de horas para todos os efeitos práticos ilimitada.

Já esse `if` no final é só para se certificar que o `Duration` restante após subtrair-se todos os campos é zero. Se não fosse, seria porque alguma coisa errada estaria acontecendo no processo acima, fato que seria então denunciado pelo lançamento de um `AssertionError`.

**[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/NDgii7)**

Ah, e se você alterar a `primeiraData` para 2016 ao invés de 2017, você terá esse resultado:

```
Total: 0 dias, 2 horas, 30 minutos, 0 segundos, 0 ns.
Resultado: PT2H30M
```

Acredito que seja isso o que você tinha quando obteve `PT2H30M` como saída.

E se você tiver certeza que o seu resultado será apenas em horas e minutos, você poderia fazer isso, semelhante à resposta do diegofm:

```
System.out.println("Resultado: " + String.format("%d:%02d", horas, minutos));
```

Entretanto, isso não vai dar certo se você tiver que considerar horas, dias, segundos ou nanosegundos também. Também não vai funcionar se o período for negativo. Assim sendo, você deverá procurar aquilo que funcionará melhor para você considerando-se as datas e períodos que o seu programa vai ter que lidar.

Comment: Resolvido... muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Seguindo [**esta resposta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266970/5524514) retirada do SOEn, você pode utilizar `String.format`:

```
LocalDateTime primeiraData = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 10, 14, 00, 00);
LocalDateTime segundaDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 10, 16, 30, 00);

Duration testeDuration = Duration.between(primeiraData, segundaDate);
long s = testeDuration.getSeconds();
System.out.println("Resultado: " + String.format("%d:%02d", s / 3600, (s % 3600) / 60));
```

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/o4Uh1H).

Lembrando que no seu código, você está comparando um periodo no tempo de datas diferentes e o melhor para fazer este tipo de comparação é a classe [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html). Para comparações de mesma data, o código acima funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Resolvido... muito obrigado.