# Como exibir o tempo que o programa esta executando?

Tags: java, swing

Queria saber se existe uma maneira de pegar o tempo que o programa esta executando, e exibir em um label. A partir do momento que executar, ele fica "correndo um tempo", ou seja mostra exatamente o tempo que esta em execução.

```
public class ProgramaExemplo extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ProgramaExemplo programa = new ProgramaExemplo();
    }
    public JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public ProgramaExemplo() {
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("---");

        JPanel x = new JPanel();
        x.setLayout(null);

        label = new JLabel("Tempo de execução .. ");
        x.add(label);
        label.setBounds(700, 500, 200, 200);
        add(x);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você obtêm esse "tempo em execução"? No exemplo não há nenhum tempo.

Comment: Por acaso o tempo que você está tentando obter é o mesmo [**desta pergunta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182091/28595)?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi "desta pergunta" o cara quer o tempo do pc, eu quero saber quanto tempo o usuário ta rodando o programa, minha duvida é se existe jeito de fazer isso, se sim, o que eu devo pesquisar pra entender como funciona. Só quero exibir em um label ou outro componente esse tempo.

Comment: Qual unidade de tempo?

Comment: @diegofm se der pra fazer, seria legal pegar a Hora, minutos e segundos. Ou pelo menos Hora e minutos. (se é que da pra fazer)

Comment: A ideia é a mesma da pergunta que postei, juntando com [**esta outra**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179093/28595).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para chegar na solução abaixo, foi necessário apenas mesclar a solução [**desta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182092/28595) com o desta [**outra resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179093/28595), já que a primeira mostra como fazer um `Timer` e exibi-lo em tempo de execução num `JLabel`, e a segunda mostra como calcular a diferença entre tempos, utilizando a nova API, exibindo de segundos até dias:

```
import java.time.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class ProgramaExemplo extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ProgramaExemplo();;
            }
        }); 

    }
    public JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public ProgramaExemplo() {
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("---");

        JPanel x = new JPanel();
        x.setLayout(null);

        label = new ClockLabel();
        x.add(label);
        label.setBounds(700, 500, 300, 200);
        add(x);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class ClockLabel extends JLabel implements ActionListener {

      private LocalDateTime start;

      public ClockLabel() {
        this.start = LocalDateTime.now();
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
        t.start();
        setText(getDateTime(start));
      }

      private String getDateTime(LocalDateTime segundaDate){

        Duration testeDuration = Duration.between(start, segundaDate);
        long dias = testeDuration.toDays();
        Duration d2 = testeDuration.minus(dias, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        long horas = d2.toHours();
        Duration d3 = d2.minus(horas, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        long minutos = d3.toMinutes();
        Duration d4 = d3.minus(minutos, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        long segundos = d4.getSeconds();
        Duration d5 = d4.minus(segundos, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        long nanos = d5.toNanos();
        Duration d6 = d5.minus(nanos, ChronoUnit.NANOS);

        if (!d6.isZero()) throw new AssertionError(d6.toString());

        return "Total: " + dias + " dias, " + horas + " horas, " + minutos + " minutos, " + segundos + " segundos";
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        setText(getDateTime(LocalDateTime.now()));
      }
    }
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que você vai precisar ajustar o tamanho do label, já que está utilizando `AbsoluteLayout`, pois a medida que o tempo passa, a string pode aumentar seu tamanho.